# Function call from another function not working

Tags: python, function

The code

```
def num(y1, y2):
 num = y2 - y1
 return num

def den(x1, x2):
 num = x2 - x1
 return den

def slope(x1, x2, y1, y2):
  slope = num(y1,y2) / den(x1,x2)
  return slope
```

Yields the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'function'

Comment: in `den(x1, x2)`, you return function `den` instead of `num`

Comment: You should indeed return `num` in function `den`